# How to use simple javascript not jQuery in Magento 2 footer?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to use javascript file in Magento 2.3 footer before the body and simple javascript, not jQuery.
How can I do that?
I have added **requirejs-config.js** file in **module/view/frontend** 
code is

```
 var config = {
        map: {
            '*': {
                hello:'module_name/js/hello',
            }
        }
    };
```

and i have hello.js file in web/js folder but that javascript is not working at all . and most important is i want to add that file in the footer .

Answer (score 1):

From backend go to content->design->configuration then edit your theme :

now in footer section you can add javascript like this :

[image]

or you can add too from your theme vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml ; before body end not inside footer

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
<block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::customjs.phtml" name="module_js"/></referenceContainer>
```

then in your template customjs.phtml you can add js like this  :

```
 <script> 
    // you can do whatever you want here with pure javascript
 </script>
```